# Groovy Class Files not working with `groovy` command

Tags: java, groovy, jvm

I am currently struggling with installation/getting started with Groovy.

With a file called `Hello.groovy` I have written:
`println "Hello, Groovy!"`
When I use `groovyc Hello.groovy` to create the class file, the compilation works. However, when I try to run the class file using `groovy Hello.class` I get the following error:
``
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
/Users/lukemccartney/Desktop/apache-groovy-course/getting-started/groovyc/Hello.class: 1: Unexpected character: '�' @ line 1, column 1.
����@YHellogroovy/lang/Script
Hello.groovy$staticClassInfo*Lorg/codehaus/groovy/reflection/ClassInfo;__$stMCZ()V

^

1 error
``

I tried installing groovy via `sudo apt-get install groovy` on my Ubuntu VM and I get the same problem when I run `groovyc Hello.groovy` and `groovy Hello.class`.

Answer (score 2):

The `groovy` cli app runs groovy scripts

The `groovyc` cli app compiles groovy scripts to JVM bytecode

You can't run JVM bytecode directly with the `groovy` cli app.

To run it, use the `java` command:

```
java -cp ~/path/to/groovy/lib/groovy-4.0.11.jar:. Hello
```

Comment: actually you can use groovy to run compiled script: `groovy -cp . Hello`

Comment: @daggett No you can't (I made the same error in my deleted answer): you still have the `Hello.groovy` file in that directory this get's used.  It's the same problem with `groovy Hello`

Comment: my bad. you are right )

Answer (score 0):

[dagget's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276664/daggett) response the answer above works flawlessly and is exactly what I was looking for. As far as I am aware, `groovy` does not create jar files.

Comment: Because you still have the `.groovy` file around. What is the point of `groovyc` before then? And what has "creating jar files" to with that?